# Maven delete local installed dependencies with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, ide

I have a `.jar` file called `OpenXES-20211004.jar` that is not available in Maven Central Repositories, so I've installed it in my project with the InteliJ project Structure settings. But when I have to install another dependecy in Maven, the IDE seems to remove the installed `.jar` file.
How can I insert this dependecy in Maven as a local dependecy?

I apologize if something wasn't explained well, english is not my first language.
Thanks for help

Comment: You need to install it to your local maven repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Maven-based IDE project you must use only pom.xml file to manage dependencies. Otherwise all the manual configuration you mane to the project structure in IDE will be lost on next Maven reimport/reload.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know! Solved Thank you!